# How to multiply across axis 1 in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of numbers and would like to multiply each observation row wise or along `axis = 1` and output the answer in another column.  As an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([2, 3, 4])
df = pd.DataFrame(arr).transpose()
df
```

[image: Result]

What I would like is a column that has value 24 from multiplying column 0 by column 1 by column 2.

I tried the `df.mul(axis = 1) but that didn't work.`

I'm sure this is easy but all I find is multiplying each column by a constant.

Comment: `df.prod(axis=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `prod`

```
df.prod(1)
Out[69]: 
0    24
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do some thing like this:

```
import numpy  

def multiplyFunction(row):
   return numpy.prod(row) 


df['result'] = df.apply(multiplyFunction, axis=1)

df.head()
```

## Result

```
    0   1   2   result
0   2   3   4   24
```

Let me know if it's help